# CSV to JSON using Golang - some data is skipped while printing in Web Browser

Tags: json, csv, web, go, streaming

I have read one excel csv file using Golang and wanted to print them to web browser as JSON Data for every GET request you make,But every time I print the JSON Data in Web browser some data gets skipped. I have double checked those data are in csv file but not getting printed in web browser. Any help you can suggest me ? Thanks in advance

```
package main

import (
"encoding/csv"
"encoding/json"
"fmt"
"github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
"net/http"
"os"
)

var csvData [][]string
var Record IRIS
var i int = 0

func init() {
    csvFile, err := os.Open("IRIS.csv")
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
     }

    reader := csv.NewReader(csvFile)
    reader.FieldsPerRecord = -1
    csvData, _ = reader.ReadAll()

    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
    }
        defer csvFile.Close()
}
 type IRIS struct {
    ID          string
    SepalLength string
    SepalWidth  string
    PetalLength string
    PetalWidth  string
    Species     string
 }

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/stream/content/data", StreamDataHandler)
    fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:9090", router))
}
func StreamDataHandler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, p      httprouter.Params) {
    res.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    // read data from CSV file
    Record.ID = csvData[i][0]
    Record.SepalLength = csvData[i][1]
    Record.SepalWidth = csvData[i][2]
    Record.PetalLength = csvData[i][3]
    Record.PetalWidth = csvData[i][4]
    Record.Species = csvData[i][5]

    jsondata, err := json.Marshal(Record) // convert to JSON

    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
    }

    i = i + 1

    fmt.Fprintf(res, string(jsondata))
    return
}
```

OUTPUT:

{"ID":"2","SepalLength":"4.9","SepalWidth":"3","PetalLength":"1.4","PetalWidth":"0.2","Species":"setosa"}

{"ID":"6","SepalLength":"5.4","SepalWidth":"3.9","PetalLength":"1.7","PetalWidth":"0.4","Species":"setosa"}

{"ID":"7","SepalLength":"5.7","SepalWidth":"4.4","PetalLength":"1.5","PetalWidth":"0.4","Species":"setosa"}

.
.
.

**Why this is happening ?**

**I actually wanted to print all the values (without skipping any) like streaming of data every 2 second from Excel CSV file**

Comment: if you need a global counter I recommend you this https://golang.org/pkg/expvar/#Int

Answer (score 0):

There's a race condition in your handler on accesses made to `i`. Multiple goroutines will execute the `i = i + 1` statement resulting in several possible values for `i`. Use of a mutex should fix the issue:

```
// ...

var i int = 0
var m sync.Mutex

// ...

func StreamDataHandler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, p      httprouter.Params) {
    // ...

    m.Lock()
    defer m.Unlock()
    i = i + 1

    // ...
}
```

However, if you want to continuously fetch the values using http Get, a better solution would be to include last index fetched in the response and add this value (after incrementing it, for example) as a request parameter in the next request to indicate the next required index. This way you don't need to maintain `i` in your handler.

Comment: Thanks abhink, I liked your good Solution :) This Almost Solved my problem. Actually I was trying to make simulation of sensors (continuously generating data every 2 seconds) using a golang server and csv data